# React input losing focus when passing value prop through Router "component" attribute

Tags: reactjs, input, react-hooks, react-router-dom

having a major brain fart today.  I've tried a bunch of solutions to variations of this problem to no avail.  It's an off-week for me and my brain, so I'm sure I'm just missing something stupid.

I'm trying to figure out why my Input component is re-rendering in a way that the input loses focus every time it receives value changes.

I need the username value to be stored in the App component.

I'm guessing it has to do with this Route "component" attribute returning a function, but I'm not entirely sure.  I've also tried adding a key prop to various places throughout the app, but no luck.

[Here's a link to a watered down codesandbox project.](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-frog-mk4yj)

And this is where I'm guessing something's happening.

```
component={() => (
  <Input value={username} handleValueChange={handleUserNameChange} />
)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead of `component` using the [render](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func) function. In the documentation for `component` it mentions the [component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component) will be re-mounted/re-created every render, which is why you are losing focus:

> When you use component (instead of render or children, below) the
>   router uses React.createElement to create a new React element from the
>   given component. That means if you provide an inline function to the
>   component prop, you would create a new component every render. This
>   results in the existing component unmounting and the new component
>   mounting instead of just updating the existing component. When using
>   an inline function for inline rendering, use the render or the
>   children prop (below).

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/input"
  render={() => (
    <Input
      key={"foo"}
      value={username}
      handleValueChange={handleUserNameChange}
    />
  )}
/>
```

Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-mendeleev-q8jr1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) in action.